# How to move the date in the cell to the bottom right in Full Calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using the latest version of jQuery Full calendar . Currently the date number by defaul is in the top right of the cell . I want to move it to the bottom right . I tried doing it via CSS i.e. vertical-align:bottom but it does not affect the first column.

/********Edit*******/

Ok the css solution did not work so I moved the html structure around

Original :

```
<td class="fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-day6 fc-last">
  <div>
    <div class="fc-day-number">2</div>
    <div class="fc-day-content">
      <div style="position:relative">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

New

```
<td class="fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-day6 fc-last">
      <div>

        <div class="fc-day-content">
          <div style="position:relative">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="fc-day-number">2</div>
    </td>
```

'
As you can see I have moved the .fc-day-number div outside and added vertical-align:bottom to the td . This works but now the height resize of the cells does not work

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the fullcalendar.css to **add** these settings to the existing tags:

```
.fc-widget-content {
    position: relative;
}

.fc-day-number {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

This should move the day number to the bottom right corner.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work .The numbers go off the screen

Comment: Sorry, you gotta use `position: absolute`. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/Zt8SS/

Comment: I am looking at the fiddle the numbers are all gone down to the last row last cell.The numbers have to be at the bottom right of each cell

Comment: That is not how it looks to me. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox(the latest version)

Comment: Works in Chrome and Safari

Comment: Yep - works in IE9 as well. I don't have Firefox installed, but that seems to be the odd one out!

Comment: Well I cannot figure out the problem in Firefox.If you could please take a look . Thanks